# Why is this recursion NOT infinite?

Tags: ruby, recursion, rspec

My friends and I are working on some basic Ruby exercises to get a feel for the language, and we've run into an interesting behavior that we're yet unable to understand.  Basically, we're creating a `tree` data type where there's just one class, `node`, which contains exactly one value and an array of zero or more `nodes`.  We're using [rspec](http://rspec.info/)'s autospec test runner.  At one point we started writing tests to disallow infinite recursion (a circular tree structure).

Here's our test:

```
it "breaks on a circular reference, which we will fix later" do
  tree1 = Node.new 1
  tree2 = Node.new 1
  tree2.add_child tree1
  tree1.add_child tree2
  (tree1 == tree2).should be_false
end
```

Here's the Node class:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value
  attr_reader :nodes

  def initialize initial_value = nil
    @value = initial_value
    @nodes = []
  end

  def add_child child
    @nodes.push child
    @nodes.sort! { |node1, node2| node1.value <=> node2.value }
  end

  def == node
    return (@value == node.value) && (@nodes == node.nodes)
  end
end
```

We expect the last line of the test to result in an infinite recursion until the stack overflows, because it should continually compare the child nodes with each other and never find a leaf node.  (We're under the impression that the `==` operator on an array will iterate over the array and call `==` on each child, based on [the array page of RubyDoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002157).)  But if we throw a `puts` into the `==` method to see how often it's called, we discover that it's called exactly three times and then the test passes.

What are we missing?

**Edit**: Note that if we replace `be_false` in the test with `be_true` then the test fails.  So it definitely thinks the arrays are not equal, it's just not recursing over them (aside from the three distinct calls to `==`).

Comment: @beavis: "==" should be recursive in this implementation, because it's trying to compare the children of two nodes which reference each other as children by comparing their children, and so on.  It's a "tree" because it's a node with child nodes, which can in turn have child nodes, etc.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(computer_science)

Comment: It is a pretty messy tree. A node should not know how to arrange itself inside of whatever data structure it lives in.

Comment: @beavis: Are you referring to the sort?  That was something we felt like adding to test out array sorting and will probably be removed as the code matures.  It's an early prototype, not actually going to be used for anything.  As I said, we're just getting a feel for the language at this point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you click on the method name of the RubyDoc you linked to, you will see the source (in C) of the `Array#==` method:

```
{
    // [...]
    if (RARRAY(ary1)->len != RARRAY(ary2)->len) return Qfalse;
    if (rb_inspecting_p(ary1)) return Qfalse;
    return rb_protect_inspect(recursive_equal, ary1, ary2);
}
```

This implementation (specifically the "recursive_equal") suggests that `Array#==` already implements the infinite recursion protection you're after.

Comment: Ah, so it does.  Technically the protection we're after is to ultimately prevent it from even being allowed on our data type, but that's something for the add_child method.  I guess it never occurred to us that it would just silently return and not throw some kind of error.  It's all part of getting used to the language, I guess.  Out of curiosity, do you know the reason for the silent return?  (Admittedly, I'm not well versed in C, so I'm only vaguely following this implementation.)

Comment: My C isn't great either, but it seems that the previous line `if (rb_inspecting_p(ary1)) return Qfalse;` is what actually triggers the "silent" false return. Basically it seems to return false if we encounter `ary1` at any point *inside* `ary1`.

Comment: @Gareth: Makes sense. I didn't even notice those implementations were linked on that site. That alone is going to help us in our efforts (as well as brush us up a little bit on reading C).  Knowing that check is there implies to me that it's easy to check for, which will come in handy in the add_child method.

Comment: Well, be aware that not everything in the C API is available in the Ruby API - the Array object is implemented in C rather than as a pure Ruby object. The Ruby calls are all you have to go on unless you're writing your own code as a C extension.

Comment: @Gareth: Thanks for the info. We wrote that test wanting it to explode with stack overflow, but we were only surprised to find that it did not.

Comment: Woah, just found out that <Enter> submits the comment. Anyway, we have been finding that Ruby has some very powerful functions that has removed a lot of work we were expecting to have to do during our excises.

Comment: The recursive_equal comment is correct but immaterial to the question. Why is this a surprise? I would like to know what language has a built in equality method that would do what the OP was expecting? Certainly not a well designed one.

Comment: @beavis: As Gareth pointed out, Ruby does seem to be designed to avoid this infinite recursion.  But I would hardly expect all "well-designed" languages to have that check built-in.  We can certainly assume that C doesn't, since it had to be explicitly expressed in the C implementation here.

Comment: I'm new to Ruby but it is my understanding that the original reference implementation was written in C but did not (and still does not?) follow a specification.  Thus, is it possible that running this code on another implementation of Ruby (JRuby, for instance) could yield different results (specifically, infinite recursion)?

Or am I misunderstanding the whole "different implementations of Ruby" situation?